# Saving current URL on Android Kivy Application

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, webview, kivy

My Code:

```
import kivy                                                                                     
from kivy.app import App                                                                        
from kivy.lang import Builder                                                                   
from kivy.utils import platform                                                                 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget                                                              
from kivy.clock import Clock                                                                    
from jnius import autoclass                                                                     
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread                                                   

WebView = autoclass('android.webkit.WebView')                                                   
WebViewClient = autoclass('android.webkit.WebViewClient')                                       
activity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
WebView = autoclass('android.webkit.WebView')                                                  
WebViewClient = autoclass('android.webkit.WebViewClient')                                      
activity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity                              

class Wv(Widget):                                                                              
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):                                                            
        super(Wv, self).__init__(**kwargs)                                                      
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_webview, 0)                                            

    @run_on_ui_thread                                                                          
    def create_webview(self, *args):                                                            
        webview = WebView(activity)                                                            
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(True)                                        
        wvc = WebViewClient();                                                                  
        webview.setWebViewClient(wvc);                                                          
        activity.setContentView(webview)                                                        
        webview.loadUrl('www.google.com')

class ServiceApp(App):                                                                          
    def build(self):                                                                        
        return Wv()
    def on_pause(self):
        return True
    def on_resume(self):
        return Wv()

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                      
    ServiceApp().run()
```

The application working great but I want to save the current URL when on_pause event fire and then
when on_resume event i want to return to that URL.

I didnt figure out how to do this.

Suggestions?

Comment: I presume you're asking about how to access the Webview in a threadsafe way during the on_pause event, because it's running in the ui thread. In java, the WebView.WebViewTransport class is used to pass the webview to other threads by setting a target handler object. http://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/518913a0da0a50347f673d4f/android.webkit.WebView?tag=out_2013_05_05_07_19_34 I don't know enough about Python for Android to say if this approach will work but it might be an idea to ask the mailing list about it....

Comment: When using Java there is a method that gets the current url that you are on. What python module are you using here for WebView?

Comment: i included the imports now on my my post

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I was curious, and went on to check things. Indeed I get a java.lang.RuntimeException: Probable deadlock detected due to WebView API being called on incorrect thread while the UI thread is blocked.
It's necessary to subclass WebViewClient and I am not sure how to do this in jnius.

I think you can access your url with no problem. The widget tree looks like this:
ServiceApp -> Wv
But you did not make the webview a member of Wv. You should probably do:

```
@run_on_ui_thread
def create_webview(self, *args):
    self.webview = WebView(activity)
    self.webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(True)
    wvc = WebViewClient();
    self.webview.setWebViewClient(wvc);
    activity.setContentView(self.webview)
    self.webview.loadUrl('www.google.com')
```

After this, I think you could do:

```
class ServiceApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.wv = Wv()
        return wv
    def on_pause(self):
        # do something with url, I don't know the android API that well
        # from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html
        self.wv.webview.getUrl()
        return True
    def on_resume(self):
        # Here I have doubts why you create another widget but ok
        self.wv = Wv()
        return wv
```

There are many parts where I am not sure, and things needs testing to ensure it's safe to proceed like this, but it's a start. My 2 cents.